# MySql or phpMyAdmin gives null pointer if it contains special character

Tags: java, android, mysql, phpmyadmin, bufferedreader

I used this tutorial: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database
This is performing awesome. But I got this name `Eugène` but when I try to take that name out of the database, it gives a `nullPointer`, however when I change it to `Eugne`, then it shows the name.
Is it possible to show/take characters like "è" from database to android?
I read some tutorials, but I can't get it to work.

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root");

mysql_select_db("peopledata");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people2 WHERE voornaam LIKE '%%'");
//$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE voornaam ='""'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))

    $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();

?>
```

This is my android java part:

```
try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            android.util.Log.e("log_tag",
                    "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
```

**EDIT 1**

```
08-22 16:24:56.935: I/log_tag(14424): id: 3, name: null;
```

But it isn't showing an error

Comment: obvious question, but one that stills need to be asked : where is the error? (aka : post stacktrace)

Comment: @njzk2 Well... it isn't really a error. It is just because he doesn't know what to do with "è", so he says it is NULL. So a stacktrace isnt't needed here. Just need to know how to add "è" in the android dictionary, if you know what I mean :p

Comment: who says null? does php extract proper values? then, what encoding does your php script uses? are you sure it is iso-8859-1?

Comment: Eclipse says it is `NULL`. How to check what my php script uses?

Comment: what do you mean, Eclipse says it is null? do you have a log, a stacktrace, something? add e.printstacktrace in the catch block and paste the result.

Comment: @njzk2 This is the only thing it is showing (Edit 1)

Comment: can you add the code where you log that line? it looks like it is after the code you posted. also, can you make sure you php actually fetches the data ?

Comment: @njzk2 Oh, you are right, even PHP doesn't fetch the name right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer:
Put this line : `mysql_query("SET NAMES`utf8`");` before you connect to database.
So from:

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root");

mysql_select_db("peopledata");
```

To:

```
mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","root");
mysql_query("SET NAMES `utf8`");
mysql_select_db("peopledata");
```